# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets.exceptions'; 'websockets' is not a package" pythonanywhere i get such error

Tags: pythonanywhere

> 23:56 ~ $ python3.8 connect.py Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "connect.py", line 7, in 
> from binance.client import Client   File "/home/utkandD/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/**init**.py",
> line 10, in 
> from binance.depthcache import DepthCacheManager, OptionsDepthCacheManager, ThreadedDepthCacheManager  # noqa   File
> "/home/utkandD/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/depthcache.py",
> line 7, in 
> from .streams import BinanceSocketManager   File "/home/utkandD/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/streams.py",
> line 13, in 
> from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosedError ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets.exceptions';
> 'websockets' is not a package

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you have something called "websockets" on your Python path (probably websockets.py) before the websockets module, so your import fails because you are trying to import from the wrong thing.

Comment: from .websockets import BinanceSocketManager I imported the file to our connect.py file like this. Local also connect.py works fine

Comment: Could you share that bit of code in your question with relevant information about the absolute paths to both files?

Comment: i think i solved the problem i got error because i called exceptions py file and other files like from .exceptions. I fixed the issues using from exceptions

Comment: Using local like from .exceptions does not give an error, but unfortunately it gets stuck on the servers.